# Display special characters in EDIT text box

Tags: c++, winapi

There is a text string containing Latin letters and a special character: "Example  text".
This text is displayed successfully in the text field of the player:

[image]

If copy this text and paste it into the EDIT text box in my program, a square box is displayed instead of the headphones symbol:

[image]

I also noticed that if this text paste into the search box in Visual Studio, it displayed correctly:

[image]

I use Visual Studio 2012, Project's *Character Set*: **Use Unicode Character Set**.

To create EDIT text box I use this code:

```
hEdit1 = CreateWindowExW(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, L"EDIT", NULL, WS_CHILD | WS_VSCROLL | ES_MULTILINE | ES_WANTRETURN | ES_AUTOVSCROLL, 6, 106, 414, 120, hwnd, (HMENU)IDC_EDIT, 0, 0);
```

To create and select font I use this code:

```
hFont = CreateFont(13, 0, 0, 0, FW_DONTCARE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, ANSI_CHARSET, OUT_TT_PRECIS, CLIP_DEFAULT_PRECIS, DEFAULT_QUALITY, DEFAULT_PITCH | FF_DONTCARE, TEXT("Tahoma"));
SendMessage(hEdit1 , WM_SETFONT, (WPARAM)hFont, TRUE);
```

The reason is understandable - the Tahoma font doesn't contain a corresponding glyph for displaying this symbol.

I did not find a single solution on the Internet.

**And the question is**: how to implement this in my program?

Comment: Why not inspect the control in VLC or VS to see which font is used? Spy or Spy++, whatever it's called is the tool to use for the task.

Comment: You know the solution. Use a font that has the glyph.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Since you already know the solution, I can only speculate that you want the desired effect while avoiding the solution. Is that it?

Comment: @enhzflep, VLC uses "Tahoma" font. Regarding Spy++: Spy++ can't interact with child windows of the VLC and VS. In case Visual Studio it captures only the main window, Performance Explorer window, Output window and Solution Explorer window and can't interact with any other elements.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, I need to use Tahoma font in general way, and for unsupported characters use a different one. But I do not know how to do this programmatically. Need an example.

Comment: If you are dead set on using Tahoma, then you are probably looking at a rich edit control, and you'll need to find each character with a missing glyph, and set the font locally for that character. I wouldn't do that. I'd use a font that had more glyphs.

Comment: Spy++ *can* interact with child windows just fine. VLC simply doesn't have any.

Comment: It's supposed to be automatic https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/globalization/input/font-technology

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, and what about drawing such text to LISTVIEW, Label etc.? For example, general font - "Tahoma", and font for symbols - "Segoe UI Symbol". How to combine two fonts while drawing text string which is contained simple text and symbols?

Comment: That's easy enough. If you can draw text with a particular font, then that's all you need to do. Writing your own edit control though, that's tough. I don't suggest you attempt this.